# Converting mod_rewrite Rules to IIS Rewrite Rules

Tags: mod-rewrite, iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm using http://github.com/lakshmivyas/hyde to generate my website, and it included .htaccess mod_rewrite rules, but I'm going to be self-hosting my website on a Windows server using IIS, so I was trying to import the existing .htaccess rules into the IIS Rewrite module, but the rules it imported weren't working correctly.

Examples of the URLs I would like to rewrite are:

```
http://example.org.uk/about/

Rewrites to

http://example.org.uk/about/about.html

-----------

http://example.org.uk/blog/events/

Rewrites to

http://example.org.uk/blog/events.html

-----------

http://example.org.uk/blog/2010/11/foo-bar

Rewrites to

http://example.org.uk/blog/2010/11/foo-bar.html
```

The directories and file names are generic and could be any values. A copy of the .htaccess I use with Apache is the following.

```
# initialize mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# remove the www from the url
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

###  BEGIN GENERATED REWRITE RULES  ####

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1/index.html

####  END GENERATED REWRITE RULES  ####

# listing pages whose names are the same as their enclosing folder's
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/$1.html

# regular pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html

# set our custom 404 page
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

I have tried various ISAPI Rewrite modules but these haven't been successful, so I would prefer converting the rules to native IIS Rewrite rules. Any help getting this sorted is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I have solved 2/3 of the rules, it's just the following that I cannot seem to get working.

```
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="false">
                <match url="^([^/]+)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{R:0}/{R:1}.html" matchType="IsFile" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}/{R:1}.html" />
            </rule>
```

Which is mapping `about/` to `about/about.html`, it just continues showing a directory listing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always try to avoid such situations. So I simply use URL rewriter that allows me to paste Apache rules as they are using IIS. That would be ISAPI_Rewrite 3 (LITE version is free), or [Ape](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/), which is also free for 3 or less websites. Since that time never had a headache like yours.